# Embedding Google Maps in a page: Map invisible although present in HTML

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

I am trying to embed a Google Map in my local dev environment (WAMP), using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ .

I've loaded all scripts needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script><script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/10/22/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/fcc600e_part_1_jquery.ui.map.full.min_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/fcc600e_part_1_myscript_2.js"></script>
<script>
      $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'bounds': true}).click(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hello World!'}, this);
        });
    });
</script>
```

of course I have put an empty `<div id="map_canvas"></div>` in my HTML before the script call.

The function is executed, no console errors at all. I see the html inside "#map_canvas" but the map is placed somewhere outside the viewport, towards the top, and is completely invisible. (seems to be inline CSS telling it to position absolutely..)

Here is the rendered HTML: http://pastebin.com/V2cMt4Kr

Here's an actual live link with the code I use: 
http://www.isawu.eu/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you have not put any css code for your map container.
Check my example : http://jsfiddle.net/Ywknf/12/

All the maps that are positioned within CSS (inline or not) are visible except the last one (#map_canvas3)

```
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas1"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas2" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas3"></div> <!--invisible -->
```

Καλή συνέχεια στην προσπάθεια

Comment: Ok it seems you need to set a height for it to work.. who would've thought!

Comment: Thanks you're the best!!   An FYI for others.  The default code given from Google says "height: 100%;".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all else is correct. You can try to look up the main container of the Google Maps container ( I believe its an iFrame) and you can try applying the following CSS styles from an external style sheet to it:

`#map_canvas > *{margin-top:-200px !important; display:block !important;}`

**Note:** `> *` symbols in this instance, will select all children from  #map_canvas

That should get it showing on your page.

Comment: I am following this: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-basic-example.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid way to include the Google Maps API v3:

```
<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/10/22/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You should remove that line, the version below should work, but is old:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

This is the currently [documented way of including the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

Comment: I know, I just copied pasted the rendered HTML and put it in static html file.. so I can show it over here.. because I m developping locally with Symfony FW